# How to get watch count of ZooKeeper

Tags: count, apache-zookeeper, watch, kazoo

Now I want to get the watch count of the specified znode in ZooKeeper. I have read the [official tutorial](http://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/trunk/zookeeperAdmin.html) and known the `mntr` command. But it's for the whole QuorumServer.

So does ZooKeeper provide the API to get the number of watches of the specified znode? I'm also using `kazoo` and how can we get this data?

Answer (score 2):

Just found this question, and you probably already figured this out but to get the total number of active watches you can run the following command:

Command

```
echo wchs | nc localhost 2181
```

Output

```
68 connections watching 114 paths
Total watches:197
```

You can find a slew of commands in the zookeeper admin page.
http://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/trunk/zookeeperAdmin.html

Comment: Documentation link no longer works. Here's the current link: https://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/current/zookeeperAdmin

Comment: For some reason, the output of that command isn't accurate for me ! I'm seeing two watches for two ephemeral nodes while I'm actually having more than 10 watches !